# C++ program opens file corectly on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, mingw

I compiled a Linux program on Windows via Mingw but the output is wrong.

**Error description:**
The output of the program looks different on Windows than on Linux. This is how it looks on Windows:

```
>tig_2
CAATCTTCAGAGTCCAGAGTGGGAGGCACAGACTACAGAAAATGAGCAGCGGGGCTGGTA
>cluster_1001_conTTGGTGAAGAGAATTTGGACATGGATGAAGGCTTGGGCTTGACCATGCGAAGG
```

**Expected output:**

```
>cluster_1001_contig2
CAATCTTCAGAGTCCAGAGTGGGAGGCACAGACTACAGAAAATGAGCAGCGGGGCTGGTA
>cluster_1001_contig1
TTGGTGAAGAGAATTTGGACATGGATGAAGGCTTGGGCTTGACCATGCGAAGG
```

(Note: the output is very large to paste it here so the examples above are pseudo-real).

**Possible cause:**
I have observed that if I convert the enter characters the input file from Linux (LF) to Windows (CRLF) it almost works: the first character (>) in file is missing. The same code works perfectly on Linux without any enter conversion. So, the problem must be in the function that is parsing the input not in the one that writes the output:

```
seq_db.Read( db_in.c_str(), options );
```

**Source code:**
This is the piece that is parsing the input file. Anyway, I might me wrong. The fault might be in other place. In case it is needed, the FULL source code is [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=22939435685937775034) :)

```
void SequenceDB::Read( const char *file, const Options & options )
{
    Sequence one;
    Sequence dummy;
    Sequence des;
    Sequence *last = NULL;
    FILE *swap = NULL;
    FILE *fin = fopen( file, "r" );
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *res = NULL;
    size_t swap_size = 0;
    int option_l = options.min_length;
    if( fin == NULL ) bomb_error( "Failed to open the database file" );
    if( options.store_disk ) swap = OpenTempFile( temp_dir );
    Clear();
    dummy.swap = swap;
    buffer = new char[ MAX_LINE_SIZE+1 ];

    while (not feof( fin ) || one.size) { /* do not break when the last sequence is not handled */
        buffer[0] = '>';
        if ( (res=fgets( buffer, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fin )) == NULL && one.size == 0) break;
        if( buffer[0] == '+' ){
            int len = strlen( buffer );
            int len2 = len;
            while( len2 && buffer[len2-1] != '\n' ){
                if ( (res=fgets( buffer, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fin )) == NULL ) break;
                len2 = strlen( buffer );
                len += len2;
            }
            one.des_length2 = len;
            dummy.des_length2 = len;
            fseek( fin, one.size, SEEK_CUR );
        }else if (buffer[0] == '>' || buffer[0] == '@' || (res==NULL && one.size)) {
            if ( one.size ) { // write previous record
                one.dat_length = dummy.dat_length = one.size;
                if( one.identifier == NULL || one.Format() ){
                    printf( "Warning: from file \"%s\",\n", file );
                    printf( "Discarding invalid sequence or sequence without identifier and description!\n\n" );
                    if( one.identifier ) printf( "%s\n", one.identifier );
                    printf( "%s\n", one.data );
                    one.size = 0;
                }
                one.index = dummy.index = sequences.size();
                if( one.size > option_l ) {
                    if ( swap ) {
                        swap_size += one.size;
                        // so that size of file < MAX_BIN_SWAP about 2GB
                        if ( swap_size >= MAX_BIN_SWAP) {
                            dummy.swap = swap = OpenTempFile( temp_dir );
                            swap_size = one.size;
                        }
                        dummy.size = one.size;
                        dummy.offset = ftell( swap );
                        dummy.des_length = one.des_length;
                        sequences.Append( new Sequence( dummy ) ); 
                        one.ConvertBases();
                        fwrite( one.data, 1, one.size, swap );
                    }else{
                        //printf( "==================\n" );
                        sequences.Append( new Sequence( one ) ); 
                        //printf( "------------------\n" );
                        //if( sequences.size() > 10 ) break;
                    }
                    //if( sequences.size() >= 10000 ) break;
                }
            }
            one.size = 0;
            one.des_length2 = 0;

            int len = strlen( buffer );
            int len2 = len;
            des.size = 0;
            des += buffer;
            while( len2 && buffer[len2-1] != '\n' ){
                if ( (res=fgets( buffer, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fin )) == NULL ) break;
                des += buffer;
                len2 = strlen( buffer );
                len += len2;
            }
            size_t offset = ftell( fin );
            one.des_begin = dummy.des_begin = offset - len;
            one.des_length = dummy.des_length = len;

            int i = 0;
            if( des.data[i] == '>' || des.data[i] == '@' || des.data[i] == '+' ) i += 1;
            if( des.data[i] == ' ' or des.data[i] == '\t' ) i += 1;
            if( options.des_len and options.des_len < des.size ) des.size = options.des_len;
                  while( i < des.size and ( des.data[i] != '\n') ) i += 1;
            des.data[i] = 0;
            one.identifier = dummy.identifier = des.data;
        } else {
            one += buffer;
        }
    }
#if 0
    int i, n = 0;
    for(i=0; i<sequences.size(); i++) n += sequences[i].bufsize + 4;
    cout<<n<<"\t"<<sequences.capacity() * sizeof(Sequence)<<endl;
    int i;
    scanf( "%i", & i );
#endif
    one.identifier = dummy.identifier = NULL;
    delete[] buffer;
    fclose( fin );
}
```

The format of the input file is like this:

> ```
> > comment
> ACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGT
> > comment
> ACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGT
> > comment
> ACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGT
> etc
> ```

Comment: Try opening with `"rb"`.

Comment: "rb" is for opening a file as binary.  If you don't know what it means, then that could be why you're having an issue.  When you open a file as "r", you are allowing the runtime to do some funky CR/LF translations in the data that you're reading, and it is not under your control.  With "rb", there is no translation, and every character that makes up the file is read "as-is".

Comment: Oh, also, opening a file as "r" as your code is doing means that `Ctrl-Z` (ASCII 26) marks the end of the file in Windows.  So if that file contains Ctrl-Z, reading the file stops.

Comment: 'rb' worked. please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Altar - What was it by using "rb" that caused the function to work?  Was it that the entire file wasn't being read, and stopped on the Ctrl-Z in Windows?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie-I am not sure I understand what you ask. After changing the code to 'rb' instead of 'r' I got the 'Expected output' (see the original question). Note: The problem was prominent when I worked with Linux files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is more than likely you need to open the file using the `"rb"` switch in the call to `fopen`.  The `"rb"` opens the file in binary mode, as opposed to `"r"`, which opens a file in "text" mode.

Since you're going back and forth between Linux and Windows, the end-of-line characters will be different.  If you open the file as "text" in Windows, but the file was formatted for Linux, you're lying to Windows that it is a text file.  So the runtime will do CR/LF conversion all wrong.

Therefore you should open the file as binary, `"rb"` so that the CR/LF translation isn't done.